# Converting F# seq expressions to OCaml

Tags: f#, ocaml

In the F# code I'm trying to convert to OCaml, I've run into the following:

```
    let rec parseList lst off =
        seq {
            if List.isEmpty lst then ()
            else
                match parse off <| List.head lst with
                | (Unmatched, _) as y -> yield y
                | (y, z) -> yield (y, z)
                            yield! parseList (List.tail lst) z
        }
```

I'm wondering about how to convert that *seq{...}*  expression with *yield*'s to OCaml? My first guess is that the *seq* would have to become a list.

Comment: Depending on how you're consuming the results (i.e., the elements of the sequence), you might be able to use the OCaml [Stream](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/libref/Stream.html) module.

Comment: Actually, the F# code I'm translating creates this seq and after that immediately goes on to convert it into a List so I'd guess there's not a lot of advantage to using Stream over just creating the list in the first place?

Comment: @GuyCoder just search for questions which are tagged with both the F# and OCaml tags: [Newest 'f# ocaml' Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/f%23+ocaml)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest translation (not tail recursive) is:

```
let rec parseList lst off =
  match lst with
  | [] -> []
  | x::xs ->
      match parse off x with
      | Unmatched, _ as y -> [y]
      | y, z -> (y, z)::parseList xs z
```

Tail recursive version is:

```
let parseList lst off =
  let rec loop xs off = function
    | [] -> xs
    | y::ys ->
        match parse off y with
        | Unmatched, _ as x -> x::xs
        | _, z as x -> loop (x::xs) z ys in
  List.rev (loop [] off lst)
```

Note that the F# code you're starting from leaves a lot to be desired. The calls to `List.head` and `List.tail` are unnecessary potential sources of exceptions when you can more easily use pattern matching instead. And there are superfluous parentheses.

Comment: This seems like the easiest way to do it.  Since the F# creates a seq and then goes on to immediately convert that seq to a list I'd guess there's not much advantage to using LazyList or the Stream module.

Comment: "*Note that the F# code you're starting from leaves a lot to be desired.*" +1 for this alone.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say that `seq` is a lazy list, i.e., a list whose tail is calculated when required rather than all at once. The closest thing in OCaml might be a stream parser, an extension available through camlp4. It's documented in the [Language Extensions](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual021.html#toc69) section of the OCaml manual.

You can also create your own explicit lazy list facility using `fun () -> expr` to represent the tail of the list.

If your lists are reasonably small, you could also just convert to an ordinary list, as you suggest.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the docs you link. It says that streams were removed in OCaml 3.03, but that you can use campl4 syntax extension.  Then it also talks about the Stream module. Does the Stream module use a camlp4 syntax extension or is it just a completely separate option for dealing with streams? If it's the latter then what would be the advantage of using a camlp4 syntax extension over the Stream module?

Comment: There is nice syntax for streams supported by camlp4. I've never tried it, but I believe you can just use the Stream module alone without the nice syntax.

Comment: There are some important differences between `seq` and lazy lists. A `seq` can have code executed before and after each time it is enumerated (e.g. to create and destroy a database connection). A `seq` uses mutable enumerators. A lazy list is composed of thunks that are mutated into values when their evaluation is forced so elements are remembered from one enumeration to the next whereas `seq` is re-evaluated every time it is enumerated.

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at `LazyList.from` in batteries: http://ocaml-batteries-team.github.com/batteries-included/hdoc2/BatLazyList.html

However, I don't think it will be as convenient as your solution.